# Java app from Linux command line stops on exit

Tags: java, linux

I use Putty to log on to my Centos server, and use:

`java -jar app.jar`

to run an app as ussual. My app runs ok, but as soon as I close putty it stops. I suppose I should open some kind of persistent terminal, but since there is no visual desktop I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run java application as background process via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27507940/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nohup command.

```
nohup java -jar app.jar &
```

Incase you need to see output/errors of your program then you can look into nohup.out file in current directory. Standard output(eg. whatever you print using System.out.println()) and error messages will go to this file.

For more details : [run-bash-commands-background-linux](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/)

Comment: works like charm, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
nohup "<command>" &>/dev/null & echo "PID to kill: $!"
```

redidirection to avoid creation of file nohup.out (IIRC), and pid to have somethin to kill later on (kill -term)